# Проблема c Application Servers в Idea [Закрыт]

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Начал делать первые шаги в *Java web-development*.

Поставил *TomCat*. При запросе *localhost:8080* благополучно отображается его стартовая страница.

Теперь вопрос, с которым я не смог справится: как получить в браузере знакомую надпись *HelloWorld* ? (через *сервлеты* или *jsp* – не важно, хотя второе я думаю многим будет предпочтительней)

Есть догадка, что с начала необходимо указать *tomcat* в настойках идеи в разделе *Aplication Servers*, но у меня **НЕТУ** такого раздела(**!**)

http://hostfotos.ru/images/ideasettin.jpg

Comment: Проблема оказалась в следующем: *Idea Community Edition* для этого не предназначена. И если я допустим хочу просто увидеть в браузере *Hello World!*, то должен выложить немаленькую сумму за *Idea Ultimate Edition*.

Comment: Гм. А каким образом связан деплой вашего приложения с IDE?

Comment: > как получить в браузере знакомую надпись HelloWorld

Соберите war-ник и закиньте в папку webapps томката.

Comment: Вопрос закрыт.